# How do you pronounce the plural of 'f" (f's)? Is it /efs/ or /evz/?

Tags: pronunciation, plural-forms, suffixes

How do you pronounce the plural of 'f" (f's)?

Is it /efs/ or /evz/?

Are there any fixed rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plural of *F* is /efs/.  This is the pronunciation listed in the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, and it's also the pronunciation I use myself.

There is no fixed rule, and you'll just have to memorize this.  Some words have a /v/ plural while others have an /f/ plural.  Some words have both plural forms in use, although one or the other may be more common.  Sometimes there are special considerations to be taken into account, as with *dwarfs* pre- and post-Tolkien.

Let's look at the examples given in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* on page 1587:

1. /v/ only

   > calf → calves
   >   elf → elves
   >   knife → knives
   >   leaf → leaves
   >   life → lives
   >   loaf → loaves
   >   self → selves
   >   sheaf → sheaves
   >   thief → thieves
   >   wife → wives
   >   wolf → wolves
2. /f/ only

   > belief → beliefs
   >   chief → chiefs
   >   cliff → cliffs
   >   muff → muffs
   >   oaf → oafs
   >   photograph → photographs
   >   proof → proofs
   >   safe → safes
   >   tough → toughs
   >   waif → waifs
3. /f/ or /v/

   > dwarf → dwarfs OR dwarves
   >   half → halfs OR halves
   >   hoof → hoofs OR hooves
   >   scarf → scarfs OR scarves
   >   wharf → wharfs OR wharves

Usually the spelling and pronunciation correspond pretty well for these plurals, but not always.  *Roof* and *handkerchief* are sometimes pronounced with /v/ plurals, **rooves* and **handkerchieves* are not standard spellings; when you write them down you should always spell them *roofs* and *handkerchiefs*.

In general you'll have to memorize which words fall into which categories.  Since the categories are just a little bit fuzzy and may change over time, that can be a bit tricky, but unfortunately there are no general rules.